# Escape Ampersand in path variable

Tags: windows, batch, environment-variables, path

In my PATH environment variable, there's

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5
```

This screws up the whole PATH --- the entries that come afterwards are not taken into account, and my shell does weird things:

```
C:\Users\bowi>echo %PATH%
C:\other;C:\path;C:\entries;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5
Der Befehl "MySQL" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "MySQL" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

Obviously, the `&` in the path is the culprit, how can I escape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you cannot `echo %path%` does not mean your PATH is broken. The purpose of the PATH environment variable is to provide a list of folders to search for a program if you invoke a program without specifying the path.

Assuming you have `MyProgram.exe` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5` folder, then executing `MyProgram` will correctly execute `MyProgram.exe`, regardless what your current directory is.

But indeed, if you attempt to `echo %path%`, then that will fail - and it should.

If you change the value in your PATH to read `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 ^& MySQL Utilities 1.5`, then sure, you can safely `echo %path%`. But now if you execute `MyProgram`, then `MyProgram.exe` will not be found because the PATH is pointing to the wrong folder name.

An alternative that works is to modify your PATH to read `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5"` (quote the value). Now the PATH functions properly, allowing you to execute `MyProgram` from anywhere, ***and*** it is now safe to `echo %path%`.

But you may not have control of all the values entered into your PATH definition. Because of the design of how PATH works, it simply is not safe to `echo %path%` in all situations. In fact, it simply is not reliable to ever use `%path%` in any command.

That is probably why the `path` command is designed to safely print out the value of the PATH environment variable without having to do any explicit variable expansion.

Even if `echo %path%` fails, executing `path` will print out the correct full definition.

Another option is to enable delayed expansion and use `echo !path!`. It is always safe to work with any value when you use delayed expansion.

Comment: In fact, `echo %PATH%` was not the main culprit, I am calling a lot of batch scripts from a cygwin shell and vice versa (without using `%PATH%`), and sometimes it bombed me with those *Could not find command MySQL...* outputs where I did not expect them. `echo %PATH%` was only the what I thought best way to easily reproduce the behaviour. I had tried the `"` way before, but I only clicked on OK *once* (see my answer), so it did not work. I now tried it once again **and it worked**. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Don't do this, it only seems to work but lets the path point to the wrong directory (see answer by dbenham)!

I've found it! It's `^`, and, most important, it seems to have no effect until you click OK in the environment variables overview window -- editing the variable and clicking OK in the editing box is not enough.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 ^& MySQL Utilities 1.5
```

Comment: That will allow you to `echo %path%`, but it breaks the main purpose of the PATH - the PATH variable would now be pointing to the wrong folder.